# Conditional SUMIF if fields are blank

Tags: excel

I want to sum the values of column B where column A has a blank field. I have tried the following, but it returns a result of zero

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A:A="",B:B)
```

I need to reference an entire column, for future expansion on the data. Here is my sample data that i am trying to conditionally sum in EXCEL 2007.

```
**A      B**
        5.00
        2.00
        2.00
        2.00
ABS004  1.00
AFS001  4.00
AFS001  5.00
AFS001  5.00
AFS001  2.00
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You shouldn't refer to the column in the criterion - should be just

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"",B:B)
```

Comment: last name warranted.